# Using bash to rename files in a directory based on the folder name

Tags: bash

I have several files with names of mac addresses e.g 50:c7:bf:2f:27:43 I would like to rename these files based on the folder names in the directory

I would like to rename them from 50:c7:bf:2f:27:43 to the folder name that I have already created Phillips

So the final output 
Phillips/Philips_1

Comment: There is an issue with your question formatting. Does your mac address really has `` character? `rename these files based on the folder names` - then post example structure of the files and folder names. You have files like `Phillips/50:c7:bf:2f:21:43 Phillips/50:c7:bf:2f:21:44 Phillips/50:c7:bf:2f:21:45` and want to rename then to `Phillips/Phillips`? Please post example output and example input, ex. similar to `find` output.

Comment: Please clarify your setup - where are the files relative to the directory? Is there only one file and directory or several of each? As far as I understand, you want to rename ``Phillips/0:c7:bf:2f:27:43`` to ``Phillips/Phillips_1`` - what does the ``_1`` mean, and will there be a ``Phillips/Phillips_2`` (so ``_1``, `_2`, `_3`, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `PWD` session-based environment variable:

You might know that, when launching the `pwd` command, you see the name of the current directory. Well, this is because every time you change directory, the session-based environment variable `PWD` is modified accordingly: in fact, the command `pwd` and `echo $PWD` are exactly the same.

So, in your case, you might do something like:

```
mv filename "$PWD""_something"
```

*Remark :* by session-based environment variable, I mean a variable which looks like an environment variable but which can be different for every session (I don't know the exact term for this).